# Heap corruption on return statement in Main

Tags: c++, heap-corruption

I am creating a dynamic array class that holds polynomials. The problem I am having right now is when I run my code, once it hits the return statement in main it begins to call the destructor and begins to free the memory from each instance starting with C. It deletes C fine, but when it gets to B I get a heap corruption error. I have tried walking through the code, but I cannot see where the corruption is happening. Can anyone help me? The exact error it gives me is "CRT detected that the application wrote to memory after end of heap buffer."

*Edit: I am more than happy to get peoples recommendations to help make my code better, but remember this is for a class and has specific rules. I cannot use anything from STL. I love any criticism you can give me.
///////////////////////////Header/////////////////////////////

```
class Poly

{

friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& output, const Poly& pNomial);

public:
    Poly();
    Poly(const int& coeff, const int& degree = 0);
    Poly(const Poly& copy);
    ~Poly();


    void setCoeff(const int& coeff, const int& degree);     
    bool isEmpty()const;

    Poly& operator=(const Poly& pNomial);

private:
    int* coeffs;
    int highestDegree;


};
```

///////////////////////////CPP////////////////////////

```
#include "poly.h"

Poly::Poly()
{
   highestDegree = 0;
   coeffs = new int[highestDegree+1]();

}

Poly::Poly(const int & coeff, const int & degree)
{
   if (degree >= 0)
   {
      highestDegree = degree;
      coeffs = new int[highestDegree + 1]();
      coeffs[degree] = coeff;
   }
   else
   {
      highestDegree = 0;
      coeffs = new int[highestDegree + 1]();

   }


}

Poly::Poly(const Poly& copy)
{
    highestDegree = copy.highestDegree;
    coeffs = new int[highestDegree + 1]();

    for (int i = 0; i < copy.highestDegree + 1; i++)
    {
        coeffs[i] = copy.coeffs[i];
    }
}

Poly::~Poly()
{
    delete[] coeffs;
}

void Poly::setCoeff(const int& coeff, const int& degree)
{
    if (degree > this->highestDegree)
    {
        Poly temp = *this;
        delete[] this->coeffs;
        this->highestDegree = degree;
        this->coeffs = new int[highestDegree]();



        for (int i = 0; i < temp.highestDegree + 1; i++)
        {
            this->coeffs[i] = temp.coeffs[i];
        }       

    }

    if (degree >= 0)
    {
        this->coeffs[degree] = coeff;
    }

}

bool Poly::isEmpty()const
{
    bool check = true;

    for (int i = 0; i < highestDegree + 1 && check; i++)
    {
        if (coeffs[i] != 0)
        {
            check = false;
        }
    }

    return check;
}

Poly & Poly::operator=(const Poly& pNomial)
{
    if (this != &pNomial)
    {
        delete[] this->coeffs;
        this->highestDegree = pNomial.highestDegree;
        this->coeffs = new int[this->highestDegree + 1]();

        for (int i = 0; i < pNomial.highestDegree + 1; i++)
        {
            this->coeffs[i] = pNomial.coeffs[i];
        }
    }

    return *this;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& output, const Poly& poly)
{
    if (!poly.isEmpty())
    {
        for (int i = poly.highestDegree; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (i == 1 && poly.coeffs[i] != 0)
            {
                if (poly.coeffs[i] >= 1)
                {
                    output << " +" << poly.coeffs[i] << "x";
                }
                else
                {
                    output << " " << poly.coeffs[i] << "x";
                }
            }
            else if (i == 0 && poly.coeffs[i] != 0)
            {
                if (poly.coeffs[i] >= 1)
                {
                    output << " +" << poly.coeffs[i];
                }
                else
                {
                    output << " " << poly.coeffs[i];
                }
            }
            else if (poly.coeffs[i] != 0)
            {
                if (poly.coeffs[i] >= 1)
                {
                    output << " +" << poly.coeffs[i] << "x^" << i;
                }
                else
                {
                    output << " " << poly.coeffs[i] << "x^" << i;
                }

            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        output << " 0";
    }



    return output;

}``
```

/////////////////////////////////Main/////////////////////////

```
#include "poly.h"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    Poly A, B(5, 7), C(2);
    B.setCoeff(2, 10);
    B.setCoeff(1, 3);
    B.setCoeff(5, 4);


    std::cout << A << std::endl;
    std::cout << B << std::endl;
    std::cout << C << std::endl;





    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Before you even think of resolving it, look deep inside and ask yourself one question.

`Why didn't I use a vector?`

Comment: The point of my project is to create my own dynamic array class and not use STL.

Comment: `        for (int i = poly.highestDegree; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (i == 1 && poly.coeffs[i] != 0)`  Just how big is your array again?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. If you asking about my print, it is set up like that because I am supposed to print from highest degree to lowest. If the coefficient is zero it is not suppose to print anything. If the degree is one it is not supposed to print that degree and if the degree is zero there should be no "x". Also if it is a positive number I am supposed to add a "+" next to it.

Comment: First of all, in any constructor/method, don't put arguments that you are not using,`const int& coeff` is never used, so remove it. I have not fully investigate, but put a guard over the delete, `if(coeffs) delete coeffs;`. Next, to create you array, you should not use the `()`, so it should like as follow: `coeffs = new int[highestDegree+1];`

Comment: You were absolutely right, I don't know why I missed that. I fixed that error cause I should be using const int& coeff. Also I was using () after my array to initialize all the values to zero. Is this bad practice? I was doing it because I found that if I didn't and when I tried to print, I would see garbage.

Comment: You are violating the principle of single responsibility. `Poly` is responsible for proper lifetime management of `coeff` as well as a bunch of other things. Nothing good can come out of this. If you want to reinvent the wheel for education purposes then create a class that abstracts managing the lifetime of a dynamic storage duration object (aka `std::unique_ptr`). Then create a class that abstracts a vector (it will use the prev class) (aka `std::vector`). Then finally create your `Poly` class (which will use the vector class).

Comment: I cannot use anything from the STL library.

Comment: Should I be making a separate class just for the array?

Comment: @Vuwox For your comment about `if (coeffs) delete coeffs;`, it is well know that you don't need the condition. Also you should use `delete[]`as the allocation was done with `new[size expression];`. Other comments seem correct.

Comment: You should also follow **DRY** principle. There are way too much code repetition.

Comment: @Vuwox It seems that with newer compilers adding `()` after array new will initialize data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I must say, that I agree with comments and you should seriously look into proper lifetime management of resources you use in the `Poly` class.
To answer the problem you're facing now have a look at the `setCoeff()` function.

```
this->coeffs = new int[highestDegree]();
```

should be changed to,

```
this->coeffs = new int[highestDegree + 1]();
```

With your current implementation, you allocate the array with `highestDegree` and in your `for` loop you access `temp.coeffs[highestDegree]` which is out of bounds access i.e. you loop till `i < temp.highestDegree + 1`.

Comment: Can you explain more about proper lifetime management of resources?

Comment: Thank you, I can't believe I overlooked that. Do you happen to have a link that clearly explains proper lifetime management of resources? I have never heard of this until today and I am always looking to learn more.

Comment: I understand you can not use STL, but you can still use a shared_ptr to an array i.e. something like `std::shared_ptr<int[]> coeffs`, which will greatly reduce the overhead of deleting things manually since the lifetime of coeffs is now bound to `shared_ptr` object which will destroy the underlying resources upon shared_ptr's destruction. In C++ terms this is called `RAII`. Also, you should consider doing a clean up to your code as well, it currently contains unused parameters etc.

Comment: Thank you, this was actually very helpful.

Comment: Just to add a bit of information, you can also use `unique_ptr` as well, but you need to do a deep copying yourself in the copy constructor since `unique_ptr`s themselves are not copyable. Hope this helps.